# Issue when separating concerns in durandal viewmodel

Tags: javascript, requirejs, durandal

After much hair pulling and google searches, I'm afraid I've hit a brick wall on an essentially simple looking issue.

I'm attempting to abstract my data access layer out to a seperate require/js file from my viewModel and am hitting some kind of syncronisation issue. Below are my implementations to demonstrate what I'm attempting.

```
// movieList.js viewmodel (paired with movieList.html [not shown in example])

define(function (require) {
    // i'd like to remove these declarations and un rem the moviesRepo line
    var http = require('../../durandal/http');
    var url = 'movies';

    //var moviesRepository = require("repositories/moviesRepositoryDB");

    var vm = {
        movies: ko.observable(),

        activate: function () {
            var that = this;
            // i'd like to remove the line below with the commented section
            return http.get(url).then(function (response) {
                that.movies(response.All);
            });
            //return this.movies(moviesRepository.listMovies());
        }
    };

    return vm;
})
```

this all works fine and can be watched in firebug grabbing the data and populating my html view - so far so good. Now to where the issue arises. If I unremm the commented sections of code and remove the http.get section, then my issue comes to light. Basically, the same piece of code is called from the *moviesRepositoryDB* js file but for some reason (which is probably related to syncronicity), it never displays on the page (though does show in firebug as succesfully fetching the json data).

Below is the code from the *moviesRepositoryDB* file:

```
// moviesRepositoryDB.js -the abstracted data access layer

define(function (require) {
    // this slightly different path to http is correct
    var http = require('../durandal/http');

    var url = 'movies';

    return {

        movies: ko.observableArray([]),

        listMovies: function () {
            var that = this;
            return http.get(url).then(function (response) {
                that.movies(response.All);
            });
        },

    };
});
```

**[edit]** -static **moviesRepository** *class* (new issue is how to return the movies collection without changing the code that you supplied to answer the original question :-))

```
define(function (require) {

    return {
        movies: ko.observableArray([
            {Id: 0, Title: "Star Wars", Director: "Lucas"},
            {Id: 1, Title: "King Kong", Director: "Jackson"},
            {Id: 2, Title: "Memento", Director: "Nolan"}
        ]),

        listMovies: function () {
            return this.movies();
        }
    };
});
```

Can anyone spot the obvious flaw in my innvocation?? This has had me circling for the past 2-3 hours and it's stressing me out :-). I know I could just go with the initial option that combines the data access with the viewmodel code, however, I'd like to be able to swap out the data access layer (db vs test code vs whatever other data access I require) and thus would love to crack this.

Anyway, no rush - just if there's anything obvious it would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the moviesReposiotryDB.js example the movies are being populated into the movicesRepositoryDB.movies property and not being returned from the listMovies method.  You either need to return the movies from the listMovies method or call the listMovies method and when the promise is fulfilled get the movies from movies property.

maybe something like

```
var that = this; // we need to reference this as that inside the function
return moviesRepository.listMovies().then(function(){
  that.movies(moviesRepository.movies());
});
```

Comment: +1 plus the correct answer. the only *minor* change being that the context of `this.movies(moviesRepository.movies());` was incorrect and should be referenced by `that`. i've amended your answer to reflect!!

Comment: argh -sorry to be a help vampire!! that change, altho great for the db version, broke the static version (which I've now included in the original post). how do I format the response in the static version, so that the code in my view model only changes the reference to the db vs static js repository class??

Comment: Jim, the static version will need to return a promise like you are in the db version.

Comment: nathan - i'm such a freakin noob on durandal (moving lots of stuff from razor to this client side platform). what would that little critter look like -(ouch!!) ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57001/discussion-between-nathan-fisher-and-jim-tollan).